# .seek does not work for resetting csv.reader containing strings too, what other method could be used?

Tags: python, csv

I am trying to reset the csv.reader but the solution posted by others does not work of course because of the presence of strings...what other method could be used instead of csv_reader.seek(0) to reset the csv.reader? I am new to this so I would much appreciate any insights...

I also tried turning the column into a list as well which causes additional errors.

```
import os
import csv

csv_path=os.path.join("..","Resources","budget_data_1.csv")
with open(csv_path,newline="") as csvfile:
    csv_reader=csv.reader(csvfile,delimiter=",")

    next(csv_reader)


    count=0
    for i in csv_reader:
        count+=1
    print(count)

    csv_reader.seek(0)

    total=0
    for row in csv_reader:
        total+=int(row[1])
    print(total)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you cannot `seek` in a `csv.reader` object, but you can seek on the underlying handle and skip the title line again...:

```
csvfile.seek(0)    
next(csv_reader)  # skip title line ... again
```

note that since you're reading 2 times, the best way would be to store the rows in a list:

```
csv_reader = list(csv_reader)
```

now your code becomes (with a comprehension passed to `sum` to make it more pythonic):

```
with open(csv_path,newline="") as csvfile:
    csv_reader=csv.reader(csvfile,delimiter=",")

    next(csv_reader)               # skip title line
    csv_reader = list(csv_reader)  # turn the csv into a list
    count = len(csv_reader)        # lists have a "len" method
    print(count)

    # compute total by summing every second col of each row
    total = sum(int(row[1]) for row in csv_reader)
    print(total)
```

if you only *need* the 2nd column to compute the mean, don't store the file fully, just data from 2nd column:

```
    next(csv_reader)               # skip title line
    col2 = [int(row[1]) for row in csv_reader]  # create the list of integers
    mean = sum(col2)/len(col2)  # division may differ depending on python version
```